# When to use if..then instead of if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still very new to rails and I was wondering when I should be using `if...then` instead of `if` or if it's just a matter of preference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`then` is required when the body of an if statement doesn't appear on a new line. So

```
if today == "Monday" then puts "Boo" end   # then required

if today == "Wednesday"   # then not required
  puts "Meh"
end

if today == "Friday" then   # then allowed
  puts "Yay"
end
```

That said, a) I'd look slightly oddly at code that followed the last example, and b) the first example can also be written as `puts "Boo" if today == "Monday"`. So, personally, I would probably never use `then`.

Answer (score 1):

Reserved word "then" is used to separate condition from code, as a newline or semicolon, so you can write e.g.

```
if true then puts "hello" end
```

That's all...